# sailsjs installation on digital ocean ubuntu vps

Tags: sails.js, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

I am trying to install sailsjs globally on my digital ocean vps but every time process seems to get killed . Any idea why it is happening and how I can overcome this problem. Let me know if more debug info is required.

Try1:
[image: Try1]
Try2:
[image: Try2]
Try3:
[image: Try3]

Comment: Do you have installed node.js before trying to install sails?

Comment: Yes nodejs is already  installed

Comment: Is it working when using sudo to install? sudo npm install sails -g ? If yes check this out: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions ... Also, it could be that you don't have swap turned on on your server instance (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)...

Comment: Today I am trying to install R package ie Shiny and this time also process seems to be getting killed. error -->  g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus) . Now this seems to be a problem on server .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a SWAP in digitalocean to temporarily store the data when installing sails or Shiny.

Try the following code to allocate storage to a swap file:

```
sudo fallocate -l xx /swapfile
```

xx is the disk storage you want to assign, I found 1G is enough for my sails project.  Then make the file enable for swap

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

The information could be found in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04